# What is usage of .item and .properties files in TalenD?

Tags: java, talend

when we create the job in TalenD it generates 3 files:

```
JobName.java - This will have generated Java code.
JobName.item - This will have contexts, subjobs and component details.
JobName.properties - This will have XML-kind representation of talenD properties.
```

Can someone help me understand what is significance of **.item** and **.properties** files? Does the **.java** file depends on them? I tried searching on the net but not able to figure out the answer. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: AFAIK `.item` and `.properties` are what's used by talend UI, and `.java` is what's generated.

Comment: RC, thank you for quick response, do you think if we run .java in standalone fashion, will it require .item and/or .properties files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.item` and `.properties` files are just meadata: jobs, process, connections, repository elements and so on...

Metadata is mandatory for editing (designing) the job and for the very core structure of Talend workspace itself, but it's not needed fir job execution. This mean you can forget about it after you have exported the job.

`.java` files are the auto-generated source code for the job. You cannot use it directly because: i. many of them are generated for a even simple jobs (external routines, dependencies...) ii. components generate an intermediate set of `.java` files using a javajet-based preprocessor.

But you can bundle the source code when you export a job. THAT java code is self-contained and useful for intergration purpose or other advanced scenarios.

Comment: This is very nice answer, and now I understood that java file are not dependent on item and properties file. Perfect!

Comment: Tnx :) but...be careful about the .properties file you get when you actually export a job. One of these files will contain the context variables (runtime-defined values), which is technically metadata, but your job will need it for executing. For more advanced integration scenarios you should avoid using this hardcoded properties file, but TOS won't provide anything helpful for that (this is meat for the premium version)

Comment: Excellent, I have accepted your answer as best and last comment as well, cheers!